# How to add iPhone XR to View as for previewing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am quite new to IOS development so not quite know about the environment of Xcode. I am currently working on Xcode 11.3.1 and I have added iPhone XR simulator to Window -> Device and Simulator. However, I cannot VIEW AS iPhone XR as it is not one of the options in Main.storyboard. (although I can launch the iPhone XR simulator). What should I do to add iPhone XR to VIEW AS so that I can preview my work on iPhone XR, not 8 or 11?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following steps to preview in your simulator iPhone XR.

1. [image: Click Here]
2. [image: Click Here]
3. [image: Finally select your simulator to preview]